# Volume question

Tags: soft-question, volume

A box holds small cube shaped blocks that are the same size. Kim tires tk build a large cube out of the small blocks but finds that she needs 6 more blocks. Takashi builds a different sized cube out of the same amount of blocks and finds that she has 85 blocks left. How many blocks are in the box?

Comment: Think of the pattern here: 1,4,27,64,100,... then create a system of equations and solve.

Comment: You are basically looking for two perfect cubes that are 91 apart from each other.  You don't have to go very far to find them.

Comment: how are you able to get all these questions? What is the source for such kind of  word problems?

Answer (score 2):

Let Kim be building a cube of side $x$ and Takashi be building a cube of side $y$ where $y<x$.

So $x^3 -6 = y^3 + 85$

$x^3 - y^3 = 91$

$(x-y)(x^2 + xy +y^2) = (7)(13) = (1)(91)$

where the RHS has been factorised in the only two unique ways among natural numbers.

Now try $x-y = 7 \implies x = y + 7$ and then $x-y = 1 \implies x = y+1$, substitute those into the equation and solve the resulting respective quadratics arising from the second factor on the LHS. You'll find the only admissible solution to be $x = 6, y = 5$, so the number of blocks is $210$.

Answer (score 0):

Say there are $k$ blocks in the box.

Say Kim tries to build a cube of side $n$, so: $n^3 = k+6$

Say Takashi tries to build a cube of side $m$, so: $m^3= k-85$

Where $k, m, n$ are all integers.  Oh, and we can see: $n^3-m^3 = 91$